# Cannot add license testers to Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-license-manager

I'm trying to add license testers to test IAP in the Play Console. I found everytime I try to add an email address, I press save changes then it says "Your changes have been saved" down in bottom in a bar.

However, the list of license testers never updates. Even after days I do not see any changes or list of users. So my license testing page just looks like this.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the email in the field either one by one or comma separated and then press the Enter key on your keyboard and you should see them getting added to the list below. Then click on Save Changes.

Comment: Oh god. So I wasn't pressing the enter key after entering an email. I would just press save changes after typing it in. Thanks a lot for this. Was really wondering why it wasn't working.